# How to make one border.xml file which can be configured with a color?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have many TextView in my layout each of which I would like to border with a different color.
I know you can create a border around a TextView by using

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"/>
```

where your border.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#FF0000" />

</shape>
```

But I have 8-9 different TextViews which I would like to border with 8-9 different border colors.
I there any way to do this without creating 8-9 differert borderColor.xml (borderPink.xml, borderBlue.xml etc) files?

Comment: Have the textview wrapped in another view - eg .View or LinearLayout. Have your parent layout android:layout_width="wrap_content" and            android:layout_height="wrap_content". For the textview, add a margin of 10dp. And then you can just toggle the background color of the parent view. I think this helps.

Comment: @sushant kunal: thats a bad scenario - you are making a View more complex for nothing

Comment: @nette: follow the juanhl's answer OR create so many border_color.xml files as you need. Like border_white.xml, border_black.xml and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it dynamically, using a `GradientDrawable` and setting it in your textVew.

There are 2 ways, you can define your drawable on your code (use your own properties), something like this:

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
    drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    drawable.setStroke(5, Color.MAGENTA);
```

Also, You can get your resource from your border.xml.

```
Resources res = this.getResources();
GradientDrawable drawable  = (GradientDrawable)res.getDrawable(R.drawable.border);
```

After that, set it to your textView.

```
textView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this in xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#6bb03e" />

<padding
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" />
```